# python dictionary with sample data set

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

Could you please help me in this, i am new to python, here is a list which contains some data

```
data_list=[[], [247L, datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 14, 7, 55, 1)],  [247L, datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 1, 11, 59)], [247L, datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 11, 59)],  [247L, datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 29, 22, 54, 11)], [248L, datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 11, 59)], [254L, datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 11, 59)], [258L, datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 7, 0, 0)], [259L, datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 14, 7, 55, 1)], [259L, datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 11, 59)]]
```

where 247, 248.. are unique identity, I want to extract the date like below into a dictionary,

```
data_dict={247:('2011-4-7','2011-9-1'),248:('2011-4-7','2012-3-1'),254:('2011-4-7','2012-3-1'),258:('2011-4-7', '2011-9-14'), 259:('2011-5-7','2011-9-14')}
```

and send this dictionary to a function which returns a result like this, 147 indicates the no of days between the 2 dates

```
data_count={247:'147',248:'329',254:'329',258:'0',259:'130'}
```

I have written a small code for counting days but i don know how to send it through function

```
a='2011-5-7'  
b='2011-9-14'   
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"  
a=datetime.strptime(a, date_format)  
b = datetime.strptime(b, date_format)   
delta = b - a   
print delta.days
```

Is this correct

```
  class a:
     def __init__(self):

     def datedifference(self,a, b):
       self.date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
       return (datetime.strptime(b, self.date_format) -datetime.strptime(a,              self.date_format)).days  


  def main():
      data_dict={247:('2011-4-7','2011-9-1'),248:('2011-4-7','2012-3-1'),254: ('2011-4-7','2012-3-1'),258:('2011-4-7',)259:('2011-5-7','2011-9-14')} 
      ob=a()
      {k: ob.datedifference(v[0],v[1]) for k, v in data_dict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: You already have the code, making it a function is trivial. What part are you struggling with?

Comment: There are duplicate entries in your `data_list`; what are the rules for merging them? What dates are retained, the min and max dates?

Comment: Right, so any duplicates are skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making that a function is easy:

```
def datedifference(a, b):
    date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    return (datetime.strptime(b, date_format) - datetime.strptime(a, date_format)).days
```

Applying that to your `data_dict` isn't that hard either:

```
{k: datedifference(*v) for k, v in data_dict.iteritems()}
```

This gives (with a repaired `data_dict` input sample):

```
>>> {k: datedifference(*v) for k, v in data_dict.iteritems()}                                                               {248: 329, 258: 160, 259: 130, 254: 329, 247: 147}
```

This *does* assume you have 2 dates for each data point; you'd need to adjust the function to test for fewer dates if you only havetup 1.

To generate `data_dict` in the first place:

```
data_dict = {}

for row in data_list:
    if not row: continue
    key, dates = row[0], row[1:]
    if key in data_dict: continue  # already in there
    data_dict[key] = tuple(map(datetime.date.isoformat, dates))
```

which generates:

```
{248L: ('2011-04-07', '2012-03-01'), 258L: ('2011-04-07',), 259L: ('2011-04-07', '2011-09-14'), 254L: ('2011-04-07', '2012-03-01'), 247L: ('2011-04-07', '2011-09-14')}
```

Comment: I just have data_list with me, how do we extract the data_list data such that v get an output of data_dict

Comment: @user9986: You did a `from datetime import datetime`. Change that to `import datetime` instead.

Comment: @user9986: You are missing a comma. I corrected that error in your post already.

Comment: @user9986: If you have a *new* question, post it as a new, separate question on Stack Overflow. Editing my answer is not the place for it.